# Apache mod_rewrite rule for redirecting an url from one with directorys to one with a hashtag

Tags: php, facebook, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im trying to write a redirect rule with mod_rewrite, but somehow it never functions, so i must be doing something wrong :(

The below is the rewrite rule as i've defined it in an .htaccess file, it should be noted that there's another  block above this one, that comes from WordPress, i tried combining that one and the below into 1 rewrite rule to see if that was maybe the issue, but that also didn't fix things. Anyway, this is what i have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =facebookexternalhit\/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*
RewriteRule ^/hash/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ \#$1 [R]
</IfModule>
```

The *RewriteCond* part checks if the request comes via Facebook (kept out of the equation so far during my testing of the *RewriteRule*) i'm not sure if this actually works, but i came across it in multiple StackOverflow questions, so i'm assuming that's fine (honestly it doesn't really matter, and i may omit that condition all together, just posted here in-case it turns out to be invalid)

The *RewriteRule* part should redirect all url's containing **/hash/** too url's containing **#**, so what this means is that http://www.example.com/hash/home should **redirect the browser** too http://www.example.com#home

I've tried a load of different iterations of the above, but whatever i try, it simply doesn't appear to function, hence this question, does anybody see anything wrong with the code? would it be an issue that there are multiple  blocks defined in 1 .htaccess file?

Finally, is this even a valid solution? the actual underlying problem is this:
I have a site that uses hash-tags to navigate to certain pages, in the site there are some sharing buttons that share the current url a user is looking at, Twitter LinkedIn and Google+ all handle the shared url's (containing a hash-tag) without issue, but Facebook strips the hash-tag from the url in the sharer (if send it along as # hash-tag, if i try send it along as url encoded %23 hashtag Facebook reports a 404 on the url), so i need to make a workaround for Facebook where i can share a url without a hash-tag with Facebook, and then redirect those url's to something actually understood by the website when a visitor or the Facebook sharing api 'comes knocking'.

Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: If you are going to redirect the FB scraper back to the URL containing a hash, then you will gain nothing – the scraper wants an individual URL for each piece of content that you want to share, that it can read the OG info for that content from. (And just different hash parts doesn’t make them different URLs.)

Comment: Boo, then how am i supposed to overcome this issue?

And how does this even get accepted by web-developers worldwide? why the f- doesn't Facebook support hash-tags anyway? Are they really that anti-twitter? and how come the next 5-10 big social media platforms all support hash-tags fine?

Anyways, any sort of solution for the problem described in the last paragraph highly appreciated